# Show hide multiple element on single onChange

Tags: reactjs

I am new in react. I wanted to show and hide the element on the basis of selection  of value in the dropdown list.
I have spend lots of time but state could not be updated. here i am used ternary operator to change the value of the state.

here is code..

import React from 'react';

class WorkExperienceForm extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {

    super(props); {

        this.showhide = this.showhide.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            featuredFilm: 'false',
            showBank: 'false',
            showWebseries: 'false',
            showDocumentary: 'false'
        }
    }
}

showhide = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    const valueselect = e.target.value;

    this.setState({ valueselect: "show" ? true : false });
    this.setState({ valueselect: "bank" ? true : false });
    this.setState({ valueselect: "webseries" ? true : false });
    this.setState({ valueselect: "documentary" ? true : false });

};

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="actorprofile">

                <section className="ds ms page_testimonials section_padding_50" style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(./assets/images/parallax/grey_bg.png)' }}>
                    <div className="container" style={{ width: '1800px' }}>

                        <div className="row vertical-tabs">

                            <div className="tab-content no-border">
                                <div className="tab-pane fade in active" id="vertical-tab9">

                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col-md-6">
                                            <h3 className="showbase_header">Let the world know about your work experience</h3>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div className="form-group">
                                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                        <label htmlFor="Category">Category</label>
                                                        <span className="required">*</span>
                                                        <select className="form-control" onChange={this.showhide}>
                                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                                            <option value="show">Featured Film</option>
                                                            <option value="bank">Short Film</option>
                                                            <option value="webseries">Web Series</option>
                                                            <option value="documentary">Documentary</option>

                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>


                                            {this.state.featuredFilm &&

                                                <div>...</div>
                                            }


                                            {this.state.showBank &&
                                                <div>...</div>
                                            }


                                            {this.state.showWebseries &&
                                                <div>...</div>
                                            }


                                            {this.state.showDocumentary &&
                                                <div>...</div>
                                            }

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

export default WorkExperienceForm;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You just use one state to check condition render like this:

```
this.state = {
  valueselect: "",
};

showhide = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value);
  const valueselect = e.target.value;

  this.setState({ valueselect });
};

{
  this.state.valueselect === "show" && <div>...film...</div>;
}

{
  this.state.valueselect === "bank" && <div>...bank...</div>;
}
```